# Using php exec() to run a C program on button press

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm building a web app that has to run command line tools that all work fine while SSH'd in. Trying to use the exec() command to call the program I want to run on button click but no luck. Code below.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['setup'])) { exec('home/ubuntu/pathtoprogram'); } ?>
<form method="post">
      <button name="setup">Click to setup</button>
</form>
```

Is there something I'm missing or a mistake calling the program in the exec() function?

Comment: What does this question mean?  Are you getting errors?  Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: Try to use an absolute path

Comment: No errors, when clicking the button in the form it shows a brief moment of loading, but then checking in the directory (the program should create two files) they've not been created

Answer (score 0):

You should have this C program inside your project directory. Always use absolute path and it should works fine

Comment: The program absolute path is '/home/ubuntu/cpabe-0.1.1/cpabe-setup', i use that in the php and still has an issue, will try moving the program into the same directory

Comment: Moved the compiled C program I'm trying to run to the same directory as the web app and used thenew path in the code and still did not execute, also tried moving the executable to the cgi-bin directory and still no luck

Comment: Check chmode for this file, maybe apache doesn't have right to open this file

Comment: Gave execution rights to all users. Would writing a bash script that executes the program and then get the web page to execute the bash script be an option?

Comment: Been able to get the program running from the web directory using a bash script, but calling the bash script in php is not loading. When running the php script from command line executes as expected but using a button to link to the php script just gives a blank screen and the script does not execute.